# How to fit a large words dictionary in a small space with least effect on accuracy?

Tags: dictionary, machine-learning, lookup, trie

I am trying to implement a word play game using a microcontroller which only allows 30kb of data. And for that I need to lookup the words from a specific dictionary of allowed words which is almost 4 MB in size when uncompressed.

I don't need to give the correct answer every time so I can compromise on the accuracy. Is there a way to **fit a 4MB dictionary in a 30kb space with minimum loss of accuracy**?

I have **already tried using an optimized 'trie'** data structure as suggested [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-trie-performance-analysis/), using the compressed trie generator [here](http://lookups.pageforest.com/) which brought down the size from 4 MB to 740 KB, but I can't figure out a way to make it smaller without throwing away a significant chunk of the words.

The 'trie' would always give me the correct answer. Is there a **way to reduce the size by trading off with accuracy** and work out a structure which may give me the right answer most of the times?
Maybe I could use a machine learning model or something related to it?

I understand that it's almost next to impossible. But the game is devised such that you don't need the accurate answer. Even an accuracy of ~25% is still reasonable.

I may leave out the longest words till the dictionary fits into that size. But that might not be the best approach in this case.

Comment: "Arduino has a limit of 30kb of code size" - what exactly is subject to that limit? Your dictionary shouldn't be embedded in your Python code.

Comment: I agree you should keep the dictionary in your data section

Comment: Depending on the particular Arduino, he probably does not have much choice and the dictionary will have to end up in the code section.  I am a little lost as to how he can be using Python on Arduino.  About the only choice here is likely to be to find a dramatically smaller dictionary, which will probably make a Scrabble-like game utterly unplayable.  Blah blah tools for the job blah blah.

Comment: I think you'd have a much easier time talking to the Arduino through the serial port. The Arduino would manage all of the "controls" on the scrabble board, but processing each word would be done remotely on some PC or raspi. The python library "serial" makes it very easy to talk to another device through a serial port. Sending/receiving data through the serial port on an Arduino is as easy as `Serial.print()` and `Serial.read()`.

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry for the confusion. Edited my question to make it clearer. :-)

Comment: @SteveCohen My bad. Changed the tags. The game isn't exactly Scrabble. It works with an approximate answer as well.

Comment: @TypeKazt I can't use the PC in this particular case. I thought of using Raspi. But the cost is again a factor here.

Comment: @AchalAgrawal I don't think you have much of a choice in terms of price as there is simply not enough memory on an Arduino. There are modules available that would allow you to attach an SD card to an Arduino, but at that price it's worth just investing into a Raspi Zero or some equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I have to agree with the consensus emerging here.  I've written some similar software (a Scrabble bot), so I've referred to my code and played around to make some calculations.  I use the SOWPODS dictionary, which is actually quite a bit smaller than what you're describing - 267,751 words, which uncompressed occupies 2707014 bytes.

Using a trie data structure is crucial for implementing AI for playing a game like Scrabble, not just because it reduces the size of the dictionary in memory, but because the basic structure dramatically decreases the computational complexity of the search functionality.  As you try out possible permutations, you can immediately stop as soon as you hit a leaf in the trie.  I bring this up because if you're trying to use an Arduino for this, you will inevitably also need to ensure that the code is very efficient in terms of speed.

But in order to use the trie to ensure reasonable performance, this also means you'll need to establish linkages between nodes, and with a simple implementation on a 32-bit architecture, those links will occupy 4 bytes each.  You could probably implement fancier logic to reduce the nodes to storing offsets with 2 bytes each (2^15 to point to the offset into your memory and the extra bit as an indication whether that node represents a word).  But even then, that means you'd need the trie to have 15K nodes (actually less since it stands to reason you'll need some code in there too. :)

I toyed around with limiting the maximum size of the words to see what's necessary to bring the number of nodes down far enough...  Bad news, you could only store words up to 4 characters in length!  Here's the number of nodes per maximum size:

```
15: 589315
14: 572754
13: 546969
12: 508959
11: 456252
10: 387321
9: 304186
8: 212237
7: 126700
6: 63605
5: 25776
4: 8208
```

So basically, by the time you've reduce the size of the dictionary enough, it's no longer valuable to even use more sophisticated algorithms.  There's just not enough memory to make it work.

In response to the idea of using machine learning models, my experience has been that building a functioning model that can achieve even somewhat reasonable accuracy generally requires a considerable amount of memory, and getting reasonable performance requires moderately powerful hardware, even when only performing prediction.  (Training is incredibly expensive, but you could do that offline.)

Even reading the database from a disk may be a non-starter depending on the efficiency required.  Caching can only get you so far.

Honestly, I think @TypeKatz suggestion was the most reasonable.  The Arduino simply isn't designed for this kind of application, so the best thing would be to offload the computationally expensive, memory-intensive processing to an external device.  You might use an attached device over the serial port, or perhaps invest in a Wifi sheild and communicate with a server located nearby.

Anyway, best of luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I already have a solution for the linkage problem by using a [succinct data structure](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=120) which doesn't require decoding for use. So I don't need to reconstruct the linkages, thus saving me the whole memory.

Comment: Thanks for the link - very interesting!  Nevertheless, I'm not sure it's enough to make onboard processing viable.  Even if you compressed the data for each node to 5 bits per character, that's still not enough to even hold all the words with length 6 or less.  (63605 * 5 / 8 is almost 40kb already.)  And that doesn't include the encoded linkages or the directory that's required to mitigate the performance impact of constantly manipulating individual bits.  To be honest, it sounds like a really cool project, but I still recommend having a backup plan involving offloading processing.

Comment: Totally agree. Actually, I took this project up as a challenge for village kids to teach them English while playing. So I'm constrained by the cost of the whole device. Using a PC/Internet is out of question as connectivity is almost non existent. So, the more I can compress, the better can I get. :-)

Comment: Oh, that's cool!  In that case, why not use a simplified dictionary that's targeted for those learning English?  For example [Ogden's Basic English Word List](http://www.manythings.org/vocabulary/lists/l/words.php?f=ogden).  Otherwise, you'll be wasting space on rarely-used words like 'disestablishmentarianism' and 'myna'. :)

Answer (score 2):

> fit a 4MB dictionary in a 30kb space with minimum loss of accuracy?

The dictionary file is likely in the format of one word per line, right? That's a pretty efficient method of storing a list of words.

So I would say, *no, 4MB of data will never, ever fit inside 30kb of space.* Not compressed, not efficiently stored, not now, not ever.

Think about it: 4MB literally more than *100 times* the size of your 30kb limit. Obviously, you'll have to iterate over the dictionary *on disk* and perhaps cache the results.

Comment: I totally agree. 4MB of data would never fit there. But, the first try brought me to 708 KB which was something which I had not thought of earlier. So I was trying if I could bring it down even further.  I may use a smaller dictionary. But that's the same as cutting down the words - a feasible option but I'm not sure if the best option in my case.

Comment: Well, if I were you, I would just keep a cache of looked up words and iterate over the file *on disk* to look it up. You could also probably use a little database module or something.